# Unable to fetch result Cakephp association

Tags: cakephp-3.0

//in my model

```
public function initialize (array $config) 
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
}

//in my controller
$query = $this->Articles->find('all')->contain(['users']);
```

/src/Controller/ArticlesController.php (line 39)

```
object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    'sql' => 'SELECT Articles.id AS `Articles__id`, Articles.title AS `Articles__title`, Articles.body AS `Articles__body`, Articles.created AS `Articles__created`, Articles.modified AS `Articles__modified`, Articles.is_delete AS `Articles__is_delete`, Articles.user_id AS `Articles__user_id`, Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.username AS `Users__username`, Users.password AS `Users__password`, Users.role AS `Users__role`, Users.created AS `Users__created`, Users.modified AS `Users__modified` FROM articles Articles LEFT JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Articles.user_id)',
    'params' => [],
    'defaultTypes' => [
        'Articles.id' => 'integer',
        'id' => 'integer',
        'Articles.title' => 'string',
        'title' => 'string',
        'Articles.body' => 'text',
        'body' => 'text',
        'Articles.created' => 'datetime',
        'created' => 'datetime',
        'Articles.modified' => 'datetime',
        'modified' => 'datetime',
        'Articles.is_delete' => 'integer',
        'is_delete' => 'integer',
        'Articles.user_id' => 'integer',
        'user_id' => 'integer'
    ],
    'decorators' => (int) 0,
    'executed' => false,
    'hydrate' => true,
    'buffered' => true,
    'formatters' => (int) 0,
    'mapReducers' => (int) 0,
    'contain' => [
        'users' => []
    ],
    'matching' => [],
    'extraOptions' => [],
    'repository' => object(App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable) {

        'table' => 'articles',
        'alias' => 'Articles',
        'entityClass' => 'App\Model\Entity\Article',
        'associations' => [
            (int) 0 => 'users'
        ],
        'behaviors' => [
            (int) 0 => 'Timestamp'
        ],
        'defaultConnection' => 'default',
        'connectionName' => 'default'   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are debugging the query and not the result. To see the contents you can try:

```
debug($query->toArray())
```

Comment: Thank you I got the idea.. i should have added 

$data = $this->paginate($query);